# Docker bootstrap unix sock is missing when reboot

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flannel

I use docker bootstrap Unix sock to deploy flannel network([source](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master/)),
which is missing after the computer reboot and the network restored to the state before the configuration.

OS ubuntu 14.04

docker version 1.11.2

## step by step

**1.Setup Docker Bootstrap**

`sudo sh -c 'docker daemon -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock -p /var/run/docker-bootstrap.pid --iptables=false --ip-masq=false --bridge=none --graph=/var/lib/docker-bootstrap 2> /var/log/docker-bootstrap.log 1> /dev/null &'`

***it warns that 'you should run the bootstrap Docker instance under something like SysV init, upstart or systemd so that it is restarted across reboots and failures.'***

**2.Startup etcd for flannel and the API server to use**

```
sudo docker -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock run -d \
    --net=host \
    gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64:${ETCD_VERSION} \
    /usr/local/bin/etcd \
        --listen-client-urls=http://127.0.0.1:4001,http://${MASTER_IP}:4001 \
        --advertise-client-urls=http://${MASTER_IP}:4001 \
        --data-dir=/var/etcd/data
```

```
sudo docker -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock run \
    --net=host \
    gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64:${ETCD_VERSION} \
    etcdctl set /coreos.com/network/config '{ "Network": "10.1.0.0/16" }'
```

***I think it will restart all right if unix sock is exist, if a need to configure the default boot entry?***

**3.Set up Flannel bridge that Docker uses for networking**

##Bring down Docker

`sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop`

##Run flannel

```
sudo docker -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock run -d \
    --net=host \
    --privileged \
    -v /dev/net:/dev/net \
    quay.io/coreos/flannel:${FLANNEL_VERSION} \
    /opt/bin/flanneld \
        --ip-masq=${FLANNEL_IPMASQ} \
        --iface=${FLANNEL_IFACE}
```

`sudo docker -H unix:///var/run/docker-bootstrap.sock exec 'really-long-hash-from-above-here' cat /run/flannel/subnet.env`

##Edit the docker configuration

`--bip=${FLANNEL_SUBNET} --mtu=${FLANNEL_MTU}`

##Remove the existing Docker bridge

`sudo /sbin/ifconfig docker0 down`

`sudo brctl delbr docker0`

##Restart Docker

`sudo /etc/init.d/docker start`

***the same I think to the step 2***

**4.Starting the Kubernetes Master**

```
sudo docker run \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:rw \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:rw \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --privileged=true \
    --pid=host \
    -d \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v${K8S_VERSION} \
    /hyperkube kubelet \
        --allow-privileged=true \
        --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
        --v=2 \
        --address=0.0.0.0 \
        --enable-server \
        --hostname-override=127.0.0.1 \
        --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests-multi \
        --containerized \
        --cluster-dns=10.0.0.10 \
        --cluster-domain=cluster.local
```

***It does not matter for the error***

Comment: What is your OS, and docker version?

Comment: ubuntu14.04, docker 1.11.2.

Comment: Could you add that to your question? Also the exact command you are typing to deploy the flannel network. And an example of what you see (which disappear after reboot)

Comment: ok, I will have a try. thanks for recommend.

Comment: Good job on the edit: I don't have an answer but at least others will have all the details to try and add their answer.